# Stop from destroying the element

Tags: jquery

So I have this code:

```
initialize: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        min = parseInt($('#js-clock').text()) - 1;
        $('#js-clock').text(min + 'm');
        if (min == 0){
            // Do Something
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Which goes through and replaces the following div:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-large js-beacon-clock" id="js-clock">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>30m
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-large js-beacon-clock" id="js-clock">
    29m
</div>
```

I don't want to have to append the `<i>` tag in the JavaScript, that should remain separate. So how do I change the minutes with out losing everything in the inner div just to change 30 to 29?

Comment: `$('#js-clock > i').text(min + 'm');`?

Comment: Wrap the text in a span. Or read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to encase the minutes in some other element:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-large js-beacon-clock" id="js-clock">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>30m</span>
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$('#js-clock span').text(min + 'm');
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a span tag:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-large js-beacon-clock" id="js-clock">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>30m</span>
</div>
```

Then I changed the jquery too:

```
initialize: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        min = parseInt($('#js-clock span').text()) - 1;
        $('#js-clock span').text(min + 'm');
        if (min == 0){
            alert('OMG');
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

and all is well again